# How to change bootlog.txt in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, logging

How tomcat writes bootlog.txt .Can we change the name of bootlog.txt if yes how?
From where tomcat picks the path and bootlog.txt file name.
Googled a lot about it but got nothing

Comment: Isn't bootlog.txt a windows startup file?

Comment: I dont know it gets created in bin folder when we start tomcat,

Comment: may be I am asking a stupid question but tell me if I am doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The file in question:

- bootlog.txt

is generated by the following:

```
Bootlog.txt - Windows startup log file 
   This file records the progress of the Windows startup (boot)
   process. It is created if you request a logged boot, and is also
   created automatically by Windows if Windows detected that the
   previous boot was unsuccessful.
```

**References**

- [How to Perform Clean-Boot Troubleshooting for Windows 98](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/192926/how-to-perform-clean-boot-troubleshooting-for-windows-98)